# http client URIBuilder encodes url twice. giving issue for date

Tags: java, apache, http, url

I am using http client URIBuilder to build url. following is my code. But whenever it has date in query param its giving me issue as it encodes date twice

```
HashMap<String, String> queryParamater = (HashMap<String, String>)object; //this is hashmap of query params

                try {
                    URIBuilder urlBuilder = new URIBuilder(urlStr); //urlStr is base url

                    for (String key: queryParamater.keySet()) {

                        urlBuilder.addParameter(key, queryParamater.get(key));
                    }

                    URL url = urlBuilder.build().toURL();
```

Is there any way to stop encoding url twice. or any other url builder?

Comment: where do you think its encoding twice ?

Comment: I debugged my code. here  _URL url = urlBuilder.build().toURL();_  url is encoding twice.

Comment: URIBuilder works fine. what variable ```object``` stores? can you provide example output?

Comment: 'object' is hashmap of query params. I am appending it to base url using uri builder. When I debug my code url is - `http://localhost:8080/services/1.0/doctor/available_time?duration=null&doctorCode=ABC&dateTime=15+Mar%252C+2016+11%253A14%253A53+AM`

Comment: how your date stored in hashmap? (format)

Comment: in string. My hashmap is of `HashMap<String, String>`

Comment: My date format is - `15 Mar, 2016 11:14:53 AM`

Comment: ```15+Mar%252C+2016+11%253A14%253A53+AM``` it's readable data for any REST service implementation

Comment: its giving me error - `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Unable to extract parameter from http request: javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("dateTime") value is '15 Mar%2C 2016 11%3A14%3A53 AM'` because its decoding one time only